# Where are Rust's built in target specifications defined?

Tags: rust

The built in targets that Rust supports have target specifications that can be printed as described [here](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/custom-target.html). You can add more targets using a JSON file, but I can't find any JSON files for the existing targets.

Where are the built in target specifications found in the Rust source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin targets are not defined as JSON (because there's no reason to and that would just slow down the compiler for no reason): https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec

You can actually find that information in [the rustc devguide, in the "Adding a new target" page](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/building/new-target.html#adding-a-target-specification).

As that document shows, you can also ask rustc to export an existing target as JSON:

> ```
> rustc -Z unstable-options --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown --print target-spec-json
> ```